# Gutenberg: How to check if a block is used in a paginated post?

Tags: block-editor, callbacks

There is the `render_callback` of the `register_block_type` function. In this callback, I can use `add_filter('render_block', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\filter_block', 10, 2);`

`filter_block` iterates through all blocks in my post ... until the post is paginated, and the block is on page 1, but I want to check blocks on page 3 of the post.

I found the function [`has_block`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_block/) but how to I combine this with the `render_callback`? The callback is only executed when the block is rendered. Is there a function for this I am missing? Like a callback `used_in_post_callback` or something like this?

Comment: what's the problem you're trying to solve by doing this? _What's the context?_ It's possible to get an answer that answers this question but is completely unusable for solving your problem if you don't share, or solves it in a very complicated and limiting way

Comment: It is about my open-source SimpleTOC plugin. If the user places the block on the first page of the paginated post I can't use "render_callback" because the block is not rendered. But I need to manipulate the headings in the content.

Comment: I tried this:

'add_filter( 'the_content', 'checkforblock', 1 );
 
function checkforblock( $content ) {
 
  if ( has_block( 'simpletoc/toc' ) ) {
      // manipulate content
  }
  return $content;
}'

But how do I iterate through all the blocks in "has_block". The content outputs nothing I can do a foreach to go through each block.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I'm missing some assumed steps or pieces of knowledge, why would a table of contents block need to manipulate headings, and why would it need to manipulate the HTML of a block that isn't being rendered? And why do you need to render the block for the table of contents to work? A table of contents should work with just the raw post content or even just a post ID

Comment: "Why would a table of contents block need to manipulate headings, and why would it need to manipulate the HTML of a block that isn't being rendered? "

Because the headings need an id to jump to. And the toc is on page 1 and the headings are on another page

Comment: ok, your question would have been easier and faster to understand if you'd lead with "I'm trying to add IDs to heading blocks if my TOC block is present, but my current method doesn't work for paginated pages, I'm using the render callback filter.....", rather than diving straight into the technical side. If I had known this then there's a much simpler method that's block friendly and doesn't cause compatibility problems and plays nicely with user specified HTML anchors that you could have taken. Your current approach is not optimal

Comment: enlighten me =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```php
has_block( 'simpetoc/toc, $YOUR_POSTS_CONTENT_OR_POST_ID )
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_block/

> has_block( string $block_name, int|string|WP_Post|null $post = null )

There is no need to render the blocks to build a table of contents, nor should you do it that way.

Note that your current approach breaks user defined HTML anchors and doesn't account for headings in nested blocks.

Comment: thanks. As mentioned in the original question I already found that function. I will try to use that somehow. I need to alter the content and the blocks within because the headings need an id to jump to. But thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks. has_block and parse_blocks was the solution in the end: https://github.com/mtoensing/simpletoc/commit/05b8e64afebfc00a2794fb0c9ef77f411c2c68b1

Comment: yes but you were unaware of the second parameter, and it seems you haven't realised its importance. I've left some notes on the commit you linked to